# Strange PHP 7 performance test results (compared to 5.6.10)

Tags: php, performance, php-7

We are testing our PHP apps on PHP 7.0.0.

At the first sight, it seems that our application's memory usage is 15% - 30% more in PHP 7.0.0 compared to 5.6.10.

We used exactly same PHP configurations, same web server, and same script files, but still 15-30% more memory usage.

Also, execution time is really random in 7.0.0, from 50% slower to 50% faster compared to 5.6.10 which has just a lower tolerance (10%) in each test.

Why our tests results are opposite to other people's reports?!

Testing environment:
OS X 10.11.3 El Capital
MAMP PRO 3.5 (PHP 5.6.11/7.0.0 64bit + Apache)
The app is proprietary, so I can't upload it here.

Script execution time is calculated by microtime(true) from start to end of execution.

Memory usage is calculated by memory_get_peak_usage(false) at the end of execution.

Comment: Without knowing much about your tests, your build of PHP, your platform, it's almost impossible to answer.... 32-bit PHP v 64-bit PHP might account for memory usage?

Comment: give us someting we can reproduce

Comment: Can you show some testcases?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: cant help without test code ...

Comment: Ok. I'll upload parts of scripts to reproduce that behavior, in next few hours. Thanks.

Comment: Using more memory should be ok (following hhvm) but it should not be slower. Please provide script.

Comment: Are you using Opcache? PHP 7 performance may be suboptimal without it.